# Android bottom zig-zag shape

Tags: android, shapes, drawrectangle, zigzag

I need to achieve below attached image programatically, is there any way? I know how to draw rectangle in `layer-list` but for the particular zig-zag texture in bottom I don't have any idea [image]

Please help me to achieve this shape

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can set background which contain your zig-zag texture portion , about rest of your control ,take one linear layout and put your back button , signup and done textview programatically . or you can easily inflate your layout to ,then what is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to draw a dashed line you can use a shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line">

<stroke
   android:color="#FF00"
   android:dashWidth="5dp"
   android:dashGap="5dp" />
</shape>
```

if you want to combine more than one shape then you can use a `layer-list` and define a shape for every item

Comment: Hey I am trying to use this drawable as my ImageView Background But Nothing work

Comment: @Blackbelt I still can't understand how is the zigzag patterns achievable through using dashed lines. This answer is accepted and highly upvoted - but still unclear on usage.

Comment: the op didn't want any zig-zag stuff. He wanted a dashed line, the one he showed in the question under the actionbar @SlowAndSteady

Comment: @Blackbelt When I zoom into that image - the line under the actionbar is not a series of "dashes", but a series of "curves". I don't think this answer correctly resolves that, but perhaps I am misunderstanding something ?

Comment: zig zas has no curves. As I said, the op wanted a dashed line @SlowAndSteady

Comment: @Blackbelt All right, I think I am wrong. The question is ambiguous. The image does not match his requirement in text.

Comment: The question is asked for zig-zag line, not dashed line. There is difference. Please zoom the OP image for clarity, it's not dashed line.