# How to make this line on Android?

Tags: android

How to make this line on Android?

[image: line]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761179/android-bottom-zig-zag-shape

Comment: pl share your code, which you tried

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="line">

<stroke
 android:color="#FF00"
 android:dashWidth="5dp"
 android:dashGap="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: it;s not working mate

Comment: it's just a dashed line you did

Comment: i need a zig-zag line